# If you use Apache Kafka as a strict message broker, can you just set all retention entries to the minimum?

Tags: apache-kafka

We want to use Apache Kafka as a live message broker only. A message is distributed and instantly utilized (fire and forget).

Could we theoretically keep no logs and just send and forget?

Which config entries should we change?
log.retention.hours and log.retention.bytes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not how Kafka works. If you don't keep logs, then your messages won't be available to consume. If you set it to a low value, you lose the message if your consumer is offline (crashes, etc).

Kafka tracks the messages that each consumer has read, so you don't need to think about deleting to prevent re-reading.

If you still don't like this approach, then just use a 'traditional' MQ that *does* have the semantics you are looking for :)

You might find this [whitepaper](https://www.confluent.io/whitepaper/comparing-confluent-platform-with-traditional-messaging-middleware/) useful.

*Disclaimer: I work for Confluent*

Comment: Thank you Robin. So if we have no usage for "reading historic messages" like if the consumers only need the latest live message, kafka would be the wrong choice for us?

Comment: that it one great big, huge, "It Depends" :-)
Kafka enables a lot more functionality than simply a fancy message broker. You can process your data within it, you can use the data to drive other systems. A couple of useful references that you might be interested in [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eublKlalobg) and  [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y5qeKmL5xMg)